# Setting a timeout on tcp client spring integration

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration

I am trying to establish a connection between socket server, No Matter how much value I pass to timeout, It is timing out at 10 seconds, What is the correct way to set a time out, Thanks.

```
@Bean(name = "mastercardConnectionFactory")
public AbstractClientConnectionFactory clientConnectionFactoryMastercard() {
    ISOConnectionProperties mastercard = applicationProperties.getIsoServers().getMastercard();
    TcpNioClientConnectionFactory tcpNioClientConnectionFactory =
            new TcpNioClientConnectionFactory(mastercard.getHost(), mastercard.getPort());
    tcpNioClientConnectionFactory.setUsingDirectBuffers(true);
    tcpNioClientConnectionFactory.setApplicationEventPublisher(applicationEventPublisher);
    tcpNioClientConnectionFactory.setSoTimeout(20_000);
    return new CachingClientConnectionFactory(tcpNioClientConnectionFactory, mastercard.getPoolSize());
}






@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "outboundChannelMastercard")
public MessageHandler outboundGatewayMc(
        @Qualifier("mastercardConnectionFactory") AbstractClientConnectionFactory clientConnectionFactory) {
    TcpOutboundGateway tcpOutboundGateway = new TcpOutboundGateway();
    tcpOutboundGateway.setConnectionFactory(clientConnectionFactory);
    tcpOutboundGateway.setRequestTimeout(20_000);
    tcpOutboundGateway.setUnsolicitedMessageChannelName("unsolicited");
    return tcpOutboundGateway;
}
```

StackTrace: Connection is available, I see subscribers

```
2022-08-02 17:40:55,989 [http-nio-8085-exec-5][8269d4eb-8c21-4256-a036-617b7b86a640] ERROR org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.TcpOutboundGateway - Tcp Gateway exception
org.springframework.integration.MessageTimeoutException: Timed out waiting for response; component: outboundGatewayVisa
    at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.TcpOutboundGateway.getReply(TcpOutboundGateway.java:293)
    at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.TcpOutboundGateway.handleRequestMessage(TcpOutboundGateway.java:234)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:136)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:56)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:133)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:106)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:72)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:317)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:272)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109)
    at org.springframework.integration.router.AbstractMessageRouter.doSend(AbstractMessageRouter.java:213)
    at org.springframework.integration.router.AbstractMessageRouter.handleMessageInternal(AbstractMessageRouter.java:195)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:56)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.ReplyProducingMessageHandlerWrapper.handleRequestMessage(ReplyProducingMessageHandlerWrapper.java:59)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:136)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:56)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:133)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:106)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:72)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:317)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:272)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSendAndReceive(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:233)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSendAndReceive(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(AbstractMessagingTemplate.java:46)
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(MessagingTemplate.java:97)
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(MessagingTemplate.java:38)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessagingTemplate.convertSendAndReceive(AbstractMessagingTemplate.java:96)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessagingTemplate.convertSendAndReceive(AbstractMessagingTemplate.java:86)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.doSendAndReceive(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:514)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.sendAndReceive(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:487)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.sendOrSendAndReceive(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:652)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invokeGatewayMethod(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:588)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.doInvoke(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:555)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invoke(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:544)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy149.send(Unknown Source)
    at
```

Comment: Please, share a stack trace you got, but I believe you are facing the `connect timeout` problem. The `soTimeout` is about send and receive operation: it just does not have any effect until you connect. We do there just this: `socketChannel.connect(new InetSocketAddress(getHost(), getPort()));` - no any connect timeout in effect.

Comment: @ArtemBilan, Added stacktrace, please help

Comment: `setRemoteTimeout`.

Comment: `Timed out waiting for response` - so, please, always share the stack trace. Now it is clear that yo need a `remoteTimeout` as Gary explains in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `setRemoteTimeout`.

`requestTimeout` is the timeout while waiting to get access to a shared connection.

Also, make sure the connection factory is configured with the correct deserializer; the default deserializer expects `\r\n` to delimit the response.